# laravel 5 error : syntax error unexpected 'if' in the middle of concatenation

Tags: php, html

I have this error : error : syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) 
when I run this code :

```
$output="";
        $search_iy=DB::table('iy_tkt')->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                                      ->orWhere('tkt_no','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
        if ($search_iy)
        {
            foreach ($search_iy as $search_iy2 ){
                        $output.='<tr>'.

                                '<td>'. strtoupper("$search_iy2->air_code").'</td>'.
                                '<td>'. strtoupper("$search_iy2->name") .'</td>'.
                                '<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no .

                                   if ($search_iy2->tkt_file)  
                                        '<a target="_blank" href="tkt_file/'.$search_iy2->tkt_file.'"> &nbsp; TKT </a>'.
                                         '</td>'.

                            '</tr>';  


                        }
                            return Response($output);

        }
    }
```

I tried to change this line to many thing :

```
'<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no .
'<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no ;
'<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no .''.
```

Same Error

Comment: You can't put an IF statement in the middle of concatenation like that

Comment: May I advice you to use Controllers + Blade ? Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have your `if` inside of setting the variable.

```
$output.='<tr>'.
'<td>'. strtoupper("$search_iy2->air_code").'</td>'.
'<td>'. strtoupper("$search_iy2->name") .'</td>'.
'<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no;

if ($search_iy2->tkt_file)  
    $output .= '<a target="_blank" href="tkt_file/'.$search_iy2->tkt_file.'"> &nbsp; TKT </a>';

$output .= '</td>';
```

Comment: I tried this : '<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no;  but condition if not working then ,

Comment: I mean when I do this :  '<td>'. $search_iy2->tkt_no;     condition after that not working , code execute with no error , but as I said the condition and other code not show in page.

Comment: try changing the `if` to this `if (isset($search_iy2->tkt_file))`

Comment: if (isset($search_iy2->tkt_file))   also this not working , but when delete this line if ($search_iy2->tkt_file)  .  the rest of code working good

Comment: @thecoder can you `var_dump($search_iy2->tkt_file);`?

Comment: Dear Derek ,You are a genius man, I didn't read your solve that your wrote it up, carefully,but now just I add to every line  ( $output .= ) after ( if ) as you said , and It is work very good , really thank you .

Comment: @thecoder Hey! I'm glad you were able to get it working! Would you mind marking this as correct so if people have further problems they can see what fixes it :)

Comment: Ok , Done! , Thank you .